# Check if the first element of an array is a digit in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I was making a program to take a list of data and separate it by the "," in the file. However, some items had multiple commas.

Is there any *efficient* way of checking the first character of an array? For example:

```
char *array = {'1','A','C','D','5'};
```

Now, I want to only do `somefunction(array)` if `array` starts with a digit, even if it is in char format. So in this example, let `somemethod` be the way of determining if the first element is an integer:

```
char *array = {'1','A','C','D','5'};
if( somemethod ) someaction(array);
```

How could I do this efficiently?

Comment: This is a really trivial problem. Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard function `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>` could be also efficient:

```
#include <ctype.h>

if (isdigit((unsigned char)array[0])) someaction(array);
```

You can also define your own, with just two comparisons:

```
#if (!defined __STDC_VERSION__) || (__STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L)
# undef inline
# undef bool
# define inline 
# define bool int
#endif

inline bool somemethod(const unsigned char c) { return c >= '0' && c <= '9'; }
```

However, thinking about performances here looks like [premature optimization](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29).

Answer (score 2):

The first element of an array is `array[0]` so

```
if (isdigit(array[0])) someaction(array);
```

is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're getting at with the efficiency drive, but there's a really easy way to do this:

```
_Bool doesBeginWithNumber( char *input ) {
    return input[0] >= '0' && input[0] <= '9';
}
```

It checks the ASCII value of the first character. If it is between 0 and 9, it is a number.

Another way is to use a lookup table, which can be more efficient if you have a more complex check (but for numbers it is probably slower — benchmark to find out!):

```
_Bool doesBeginWithNumber( char *input ) {
    const static _Bool cases[256] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    }
    return cases[(unsigned char) input];
}
```

And another option, as pointed out by others, is good old standardised `isdigit`:

```
_Bool doesBeginWithNumber( char *input ) {
    return isdigit( input[0] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) reference page already includes a working example that basically does what you need.